# How to migrate ManagedCertificates from regional to zonal GKE cluster without down time

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am currently running a regional GKE cluster and want to migrate to a new zonal one. The old cluster has an Ingress Object with a public IP using Google Managed Certificates for HTTPS termination.

My migration plan is:

1. Create new zonal cluster.
2. `kubectl apply -f clusterConfig.yaml`.
3. Move public IP to new cluster.

The big problem with this is, that the ManagedCertificates will need at least 15 min. after the IP is moved to become ready. This will render all services unavailable within this time period. Is there any way to use the old ManagedCertificates' keys in the new cluster until the new ManagedCertificates are ready?

Comment: You need to reuse the IP from the older cluster? If you are using DNS, you could create a new IP, generate the certificates and change the DNS to the new IP after ready.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A new IP is possible, but how can I generate the new certificates while the DNS records still refer to the old IP? As far as I understood, the ManagedCertificates access the domain during creation?

Comment: I think I found a way to help you. I will test in my lab and camoe back asap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some researches and tests in my lab account, I'm going to explain how you can reuse/reassign the current ManagedCertificate in many LoadBalancers.

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#managed_certificate_not_provisioned_when_domain_resolves_to_ip_addresses_of_multiple_load_balancers):

> When your domain resolves to IP addresses of multiple load balancers (multiple Ingresses), you should create a single ManagedCertificate resource and attach it to all the Ingresses. If you instead create many ManagedCertificate resources and attach each of them to a separate Ingress, the Certificate Authority may not be able to verify the ownership of your domain and some of your certificates may not be provisioned

I'm running a simple application in a Kubernetes 1.17.4 on a Regional cluster (old), and want to move to a new Zonal cluster using GKE kubernetes 1.17.5.

In the old cluster I've created a `ManagedCertified` and an ingress.
In the new cluster i'm going to create only a ingress reusing the previous `ManagedCertificate`:

1. **New LoadBalancer IP**

Let's start allocating a new IP address for the LoadBalancer

```
gcloud compute addresses create newip --global
```

Get the new IP with the following command:

```
gcloud compute addresses describe newip --global
```

Result:

```
address: 34.107.xxx.xxx
...
```

2. **Deploying the application**

For this example I'm using a simple `echo-server` deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo
        image: mendhak/http-https-echo
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: echo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

3. **Creating the ingress**

You need to get the value from the key `ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert` **from the old ingress**, and configure the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` with the **new ip**
name's

You can use the command `kubectl get ing old-ingress -oyaml` to get the key on the previous cluster.

**Why?** This is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#managed_certificate_not_provisioned_when_domain_resolves_to_ip_addresses_of_multiple_load_balancers):

> Managed Certificates communicate with Ingress using the `kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert` annotation.

and [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#ingress_annotations):

> ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: Use this annotation to reference the certificates and keys

The final yaml will looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-new-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: newip #new ip name
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: mcrt-a798051f-a50d-4b38-84b1-xxxxxxxxxxxx # from the old ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Apply the ingress spec and wait for the Load balancer provisioning... after few minutes verify if everything is ok using `kubectl get ing` and try to curl the ip (SSL will not match yet, because you are using the ip)

```
curl -IL -k 34.107.xxx.xxx

HTTP/2 200
x-powered-by: Express
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 647
etag: W/"287-qCxPIULxqrMga5xHN8AAKMHsUi4"
date: Wed, 20 May 2020 11:49:14 GMT
via: 1.1 google
alt-svc: clear
```

4. **Changing DNS record**

At this point we have a functional application with ingress using the SSL provisioned from the old cluster.

To move all traffice from the previous cluster to the new, you just need to change the DNS record using the new ip.

Depending what DNS provider you are using, you can create a new dns entry with the new ip and control the traffic using dns weight, round-robin etc...

**References:**

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs

Comment: Thanks for your well researched answer! That is exactly what I ended up doing and it works well. I would not have been able to write it down so well, but can confirm that this is indeed working. So, I accepted and upvoted :) May it help others, considering the recent change in pricing structure on GKE.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the answer. It is still not clear how to complete the migration e.g. remove/delete old cluster with the managed certificate that was initially created for the domain? Do we delete the IP address used in old cluster and then create new managed certificate in the new Cluster, and finally update new Ingerss (by removing ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: annotation and adding new cert)?

Comment: @bogumbiker how did you remove/delete old cluster with the managed certificate that was initially created for the domain in the end? I am afraid delete old cluster and recreate cluster will have significant downtime.